# How to create a shining sun in OpenGL ES 2 (on Android)

Tags: opengl-es2

Let's say I created a space scene in OpenGL ES 2 similar to this one:

[image]

At the moment my sun is just a small texture similar to the one in the image that I place somewhere far, but it obviously looks very static. How would I make my sun shine & look alive?

EDIT: This is just an example image and all I care about is the sun. In my implementation the lighting and everything else is fine, but the sun itself (which is just a texture at the moment), doesn't "animate"/shine at all. I'm trying to find out how to make my sun shine and look like it's alive.

Comment: HDR and bloom, lens flares, crepescular rays....lots of options.

Comment: How would lens flares help me? Maybe a spritesheet animation of lens flare should give the impression the sun in shining, because otherwise all I get is a sun that is still static and not doing anything.

Comment: I hope this is just a mockup of some sort, because the lighting definitely isn't coming from the sun, which contributes to the static look. Anyways, try dimming the surrounding scene when looking directly/close to the sun. That way the the rays should also shorten/lengthen as they dim/intensify.

Comment: @Fault Updated my question. All I'm trying to do is make the sun itself *look* realistic. My scene already has realistic lighting.

Comment: Ironically enough, the sun from far away would look very static. The only reason it wouldn't look simply like a white dot it because of *faulty hardware*. By which I mean either your eyes, or a camera. With your eyes, it's going to be light diffracting through your eyelashes. With a camera, it'll be something like lens flare. And then of course light "bleeding", which can is generally simulated with bloom...

Comment: @Fault don't forget astigmatism as a hardware fault.  Stars don't twinkle, but your eye lenses do morph poorly.